# SMS not delivered to India number using AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

You can also find this on the AWS thread: [AWS Developer Forums: No SMS delivered on India phone number ...](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=282713)

```
var sns = new AWS.SNS({ "region": "ap-south-1" }); 

var params = {
        Message: 'this is a test message',
        PhoneNumber: '+91xxx'
      };
sns.setSMSAttributes({
        attributes: {
            DefaultSMSType: 'Transactional'
        }
});
sns.publish(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log("success "+JSON.stringify(data)); // successful response
 });
```

I got the message-id in response, but the SMS never got deliverd.

```
{
  ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '1d6dd652-fd57-5f7d-ad7f-XXXXX' },
  MessageId: '431efd91-7356-5e8e-9384-XXXX' 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During research, I found out that I didn't select the "Default Messaging Type " to Transactional before in the console (see the image). Once I selected it to Transactional, I started receiving the sms.

[image]

Comment: You are a life saver :)

Comment: Do users need to subscribe to receive the sms?